# Union grouping in bipartite graphs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, grouping, bipartite

I'm trying to figure out a good (and fast) solution to the following problem:

I have two models I'm working with, let's call them players and teams. A player can be on multiple teams and a team can have multiple players). I'm working on creating a UI element on a form that allows a user to select multiple teams (checkboxes). As the user is selecting (or deselecting) teams, I'd like to display the teams grouped by the players.

So for examples:

1. If the selected teams have no players that intersect, each team would have its own section.
2. If the user selects two teams and they have the same players, there would be one section containing the names of the two teams and all the players.
3. If TEAM_A has players [1, 2, 4, 5] and TEAM_B has players [1, 3, 5, 6]. There would be the following sections: SECTION_X = [TEAM_A, TEAM_B, 1, 5], SECTION_Y = [TEAM_A, 2, 3], SECTION _Z = [TEAM_B, 3, 5]

I hope that's clear. Essentially, I want to find the teams that players have in common and group by that. I was thinking maybe there is a way to do this by navigating a bipartite graph? Not exactly sure how though and I might be overthinking it. I was hoping to do this by creating some type of data structure on the server and using it on the client. I would love to hear your suggestions and I appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: You may end up with a whole lot of sections. Consider e.g. 4 teams, each with 8 out of 15 players: A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], B=[1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12], C=[1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14], D=[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]. Now each of these players is on a different subset of teams, and if I understand you correctly, they should each get their own section. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have each player wrapper track the selected teams that it is on

```
class PlayerWrapper {
  Player player;
  TeamList teamList;
}

class TeamList {
  private List<Team> teams;
  int hashValue = // hash value derived from teams list
  void add(Team team) {
    teams.add(team);
    hashValue = // update hash value
  }
}
```

Then maintain a hash table of player sets, and a hash table of player wrappers

```
HashTable<TeamList, Set<Player>> playerSets
HashTable<Player, PlayerWrapper> playerWrappers
```

When the user selects a new team, iterate through the team's players and retrieve the player wrappers from `playerWrappers`.  For each player wrapper, retrieve the `Set<Player>` from `playerSets` and remove the player from the set, then add the new team to the wrappers `TeamList`, retrieve the `Set<Player>` from `playerSets` and add the player to the set.

```
void updatePlayer(Team team, Player player) {
  PlayerWrapper wrapper = playerWrappers.get(player);
  Set<Player> set = playerSets.get(wrapper.teamList);
  set.remove(player);
  wrapper.teamList.add(team);
  set = playerSets.get(wrapper.teamList);
  set.add(player);
}
```

Assuming you're using hash sets for `Set<Player>` this should on average require constant time to process a team's player.  Deselecting a team will function the same way, except that you'll remove the team from `wrapper.teamList` instead of adding it, and you'll have a linear time search through the `TeamList` to locate and remove the team.  The use of a `List` in `TeamList` assumes that the UI will prevent duplicate teams; be careful using a `Set` instead, because it may be more difficult to ensure that two wrappers' `TeamLists` will have the same hashValue (i.e. you may need to take steps to ensure that both wrappers' `TeamLists` return their teams in the same order - something like a java [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) would do the trick)